# How to Generate a Mask from Semantic Image Segmentation Output?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation

I recently started creating a U-Net for a segmentation problem. However, after training the mask is only in one channel(400,400,1) as opposed to a three channel color image(400,400,3).

I attached the masks that I am referring to. The left mask is my input mask and the right mask is the mask that my model outputs.

[image]

To get the output mask I use the Tensorflow Tutorial for Image Segmentation. The code:

```
def create_mask1(pred_mask):
    pred_mask = tf.argmax(pred_mask, axis=-1)
    pred_mask = pred_mask[..., tf.newaxis]
    return pred_mask[0]
....
plt.imshow(create_mask1(segmentation_model.predict(image)))
```

Is there another way for me to generate masks? And if there is another way, do I have to retrain my model to use that method?

Comment: `(400, 400, 1)` is three dimensions. It just only has a single component in one of those dimensions. If the question is how to transform the coloured mask to greyscale, then first you need a rule that explains the transformation. In your case, it seems that you could try to determine the *hue* of each RGB value and map yellowish things to black and purplish things to white.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry for any confusion. I was trying to figure if 1) it is normal for an output to look like that and 2) if I had to edit the channels by editing the ouput mask.